# How to access and loop over nested JSON items in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

My first time doing this so please bear with me.

Trying to access some items from my local JSON file. In this case, the 'model'.

**JSON:**

```
{
   "machines":[
      {
         "category":"Skid Steer and Compact Track Loaders",
         "product_details":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "model":"226D3",
               // ^^^ what I want to access
               "power":"67.1",
               "rated_operating_capacity":"1550",
               "operating_weight":"5849",
               "description":"Built for tough work, the Caterpillar® Skid Steer Loaders incorporate big iron features. These machines deliver Cat reliability, durability, and efficient operation, even in the toughest working conditions.",
               "image":"https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Caterpillar/CM20190910-c686b-0fdbf"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "model":"232D3",
               // ^^^ what I want to access
               "power":"67.1",
               "rated_operating_capacity":"1900",
               "operating_weight":"6514",
               "description":"Built for tough work, the Caterpillar® Skid Steer Loaders incorporate big iron features. These machines deliver Cat reliability, durability, and efficient operation, even in the toughest working conditions.",
               "image":"https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Caterpillar/CM20190730-e346c-4dbd8"
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "model":"236D3",
               // ^^^ what I want to access
               "power":"74.3",
               "rated_operating_capacity":"1800",
               "operating_weight":"6567",
               "description":"Built for tough work, the Caterpillar® Skid Steer Loaders incorporate big iron features. These machines deliver Cat reliability, durability, and efficient operation, even in the toughest working conditions.",
               "image":"https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Caterpillar/CM20190926-ee588-778c4?wid=735"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**And below is where I load the data and map over it to display:**

```
export default function MachineList() {
  // Load in global state
  const { data } = useAPI();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        {data.map((item) => (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-4">
              <MachineCard title={item.product_details.model} /> 
                                 {/* ^ how I'm trying to access it */}            
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is there a way I can access the 'model' and make it output using .map?

Comment: maybe:  const { machines } = useAPI();

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the structure of your data, you need to change the array you are using in `map` to `data.machines[0].product_details`:

```
{data.machines && data.machines[0].product_details.map((item) => (
```

and you can then use:

```
<MachineCard title={item.model} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dario. Made the adjustments and received the error, 'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'. Any idea?

Comment: This means that `data` object has no `machines` property. Make sure the naming is correct; also make sure you are waiting for the data to be loaded before accessing `machines` array; if you wanna be on the safe side, add the condition `data.machines && ` (check updated answer)

Comment: Got it working.

Just had to change `item.product_details.model` to `item.product_details[0].model`, and keep `data.map(item)..`.